# LinkedIn share article throws something went wrong exception

Tags: linkedin-api

Recently we are facing issues with sharing an article from LinkedIn through our website. The following is the webpage having LinkedIn button at the bottom.

https://www.perpetual.com.au/insights/so-far-so-good-as-the-recovery-rally-continues

When user clicks on this button, a popup window will be displayed with LinkedIn login page. Providing the userid and password throws an exception "Something went wrong".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN05E.png)

This has been working for long time and we are recently facing this issue. There is some other article(url given below) is working fine.

https://www.perpetual.com.au/insights/equity-market-rally-set-to-boost-income

We are unable to find the root cause of the issue. This issue has happened some 2 months ago and it was resolved automatically. Again issue occurred once again recently.

Appreciate your help in finding the root cause.

We are receiving following error in console

```
Error while processing route: inshare.index Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview [inshare-common/routes/index] Error: Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview [inshare-common/routes/index]
    at https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6jo0t9xz6vly9fmfoukgr7muj:189:561
    at b (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:7153:12)
    at g (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:7152:3)
    at p (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:7139:1)
    at invokeWithOnError (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:6009:199)
    at d.flush (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:5993:20)
    at p.flush (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:6021:52)
    at B._end (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:6122:9)
    at B._boundAutorunEnd (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/1bncnki27iq14axs5xmo7o2nr:6059:6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your LinkedIn share to use the updated url as below:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.perpetual.com.au/insights/equity-market-rally-set-to-boost-income

Also make sure you have the below meta tags defined for your page

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='images/image.png'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description '/>
<meta property='og:url' content='https://www.articleURL' />
```

Answer (score 0):

We just noticed ours was broken, and I got it working by replacing an `&amp;` between query arguments with a simple `&`